# Accidentally clicked "Don't save" in new Word document

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, file-recovery, osx-yosemite, microsoft-office-2011

After accidentally closing a new document without saving, on Windows I feel I might have a chance at finding temporary files.

On a Mac with MS Office 2011 is there somewhere I might find a scratch file for a document that was never saved?

Comment: What version of windows and which version of MS office?

Comment: @user2813274 It's Mac OS X 10... MS Office 2011

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the application crashed, then it would still be possible to recover it at `/Users/ username/Library/Application Support/ Microsoft/Office/Office 2011 AutoRecovery`.

However, if you close a file and click **Don't Save,** [the file is deleted from the AutoRecovery folder.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-save-and-recover--files-6c6425b1-6559-4bbf-8f80-4f038402ff02?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

You can:

1. Look in your trash for a "Recovered items" folder.
2. In **Finder,** select **Go > Go to folder,** type `/private/var/folders` and look for files named "**Word Work File"** inside a **"Temporary items"** folder. Drag the files or folders to the Desktop (or anywhere else) before dropping them on Word's icon. MAKE A COPY FIRST!

However, the chances of finding anything useful are [remote,](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/how-do-i-retrieve-an-unsaved-word-file-on-a-mac/936ebc5e-359c-41b7-881b-d128ffe0c6cc) as the document would never have made it from RAM to your hard disk. (Though some users seem to have had some success with the second method)

**Final Method: (from the link above)**

1. Go to **Finder** and open the HD icon in your desktop
2. Press **Command F** (for Find)
3. Next to **Search,** select **This Mac**
4. Click on the first dropdown menu and select **Last modified date**
5. Click on the second dropdown menu and select **within last**
6. Click on the blank field and type **1** (the search operation will start at this point)
   Make sure the third dropdown menu says **Days**
7. In the main menu bar, select **View > Show view options** and enable **Date Modified**
8. In the search results window, click on the title **Date Modified** to sort files by date
9. Read through the list to identify your file. If a likely candidate is found, **Option Drag** it to the Desktop (this will copy the file, making sure you don't move any required files out of where they might be needed), then try to open it by dropping it on Word's icon.

If you do find one or more file that contain part of the text that are looking for, but also a lot of garbage, try to clean it up as follows (you will still get a lot of garbage and no format at all):

1. In Word, select File > Open
2. In the dropdown menu, select **Recover text from any file**
3. Locate the file on the Desktop and open it.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson. Unfortunately `Word Work File` isn't there. There are folders with two letter names. Should I bother looking through these: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rnPFt.png?

Comment: I don't see any harm in trying, if that doesn't work try the last resort (updating answer).

Comment: But remember the chances of finding the file is slim, and you'll need to remove much garbage from it if you find it :)

Comment: Thanks for tip. Search Mac helped me. My file was in /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word. I cannot believe this happened even though I did save the file. Stupid Word. I have Word for Mac 15.19.1 btw.